# How would I parse in a bash script date_value _space_ date_value

Tags: regex, bash

I am trying to import a tsv file into a mysql db but I am having trouble since the file has no unique delimiters to identify where a new row starts. The only unique identifier is a date followed by a space followed by time. Example: `6/19/2010 16:04:43`

Could someone please point me in the right direction or help me make a bash script that puts a semicolon `";"` in front of that string. So the end result will be `;6/19/2010 16:04:43`

The tricky part is that in this file there will be other date fields and other time fields but this is the only string that will have a space in between the two.

Answer (score 1):

`cat file | sed 's#[0-9]\{1,2\}/[0-9]\{1,2\}/[0-9]\{4\} #;&#g' >resultfile`. Test before using.

Comment: This script is correct for the above case,date space time, except it also does it when the format of the string is date tab time. Is there any way to get rid of the second scenario?

Comment: It is almost perfect but for some reason some strings are not being touched. 

example: 6/5/2010 17:00:30
         7/3/2010 16:53:50

Would you happen to have any idea why?

Comment: here is an example of the data set: http://pastebin.com/5fFf8NQZ

For some reason the first entry is skipped but the others are fine. 

ps. This is just a small part of a larger file so that first entry is not really first. There is something unique about that string.

Comment: @Igor The uniqueness is that it contains one digit for the second date column, while the regex matches exactly to. Updated, once more :)

Comment: It works perfectly, Thank you so incredibly much. You have no idea how much you helped me out. Are there any books or online sites that you could recommend to learn awk or sed?

Comment: @Igor: Do a search here. There have been questions asked about such books.